# get_the_excerpt() is not working as expected - returns wrong text

Tags: posts, theme-development, excerpt

In my template's 'footer.php', I'm attempting to generate a list of the four most recent blog posts, showing the featured image, title, excerpt, and a link to view.

The title, featured image, and URL are correctly generated, but the function `get_the_excerpt($post_id)` is returning unexpected results.

Sometimes, it returns the correct text excerpted from the blog post.  Other times (i.e. upon refresh), it returns an excerpt from the first **page** of the site, not even a blog post.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Dumping the $rp variable shows the correct posts are returned.  I'm using `setup_postdata()` per [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt).

Am I using get_the_excerpt() incorrectly?

Note that the posts don't have manually-defined excerpts. I'm simply trying to get an auto-generated excerpt of each post.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- Recent posts -->
        <div class="recent-posts row">
            <?php 
            // Get list of recent posts:
            $rp = wp_get_recent_posts([
                'numberposts' => 4          
            ]);
            var_export($rp);

            foreach($rp as $p) : 
                global $post;
                $post = $p;
                setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card" width=>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $p['ID']) ?>" alt="<?=$p['post_title'] ?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="<?=get_permalink( $p['ID'] ) ?>"><?=$p['post_title'] ?></a></h5>
                            <p class="card-text"><?=get_the_excerpt( $p['ID'] )?></p>
                            <a href="<?=get_permalink( $p['ID']) ?>">Read full post</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
        </div> <!-- end recent-posts -->
```

**UPDATE:**
So I got this to work, thanks to @SallyCJ in the comments below.  Here's how:

When iterating through the posts returned by `wp_get_recent_posts()`, each post needs to be retrieved as an object and assigned to the global $post variable:

```
// (inside loop)
global $post;
$post = get_post($p['ID'], OBJECT);  // Retrieve the post as an object.
// NOW `get_the_excerpt()` works properly.
```

NOTE that there appears to be a bug in get_the_excerpt, as it completely ignores any argument passed in.  I can pass any post ID, and it always returns an excerpt for the current post.

Comment: You need to *assign the global $post variable * as mentioned [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

Comment: @sally That doesn't work.  I tried it, but I still get the same result: the same excerpt is displayed for *all* posts.  See my updated code above.  Why do I need to do this at all, if I'm passing the Post ID to get_the_excerpt()?  get_the_excerpt() is supposed to find the correct excerpt based on post ID.  This output doesn't make sense!

Comment: Have you tried to use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset the query instead of wp_reset_query()?

Comment: @hamdirizal am I supposed to do that at the end of *each* post, or at the end of the entire loop?

Comment: At the end of the entire loop.

Comment: @hamdirizal That doesn't help. That would only affect subsequent post loops, not what happens previously.

Comment: @RyanGriggs `setup_postdata()` is expecting a post object and not an array - your `$p` is currently an array - `$post = $p; // array, but needs to be an object`.

Comment: @SallyCJ why does this even matter, if I'm passing a Post ID to the get_the_post_thumbnail()?  According to the docs, it doesn't need the global $post to be updated unless no arguments are being passed in...

Comment: "*`setup_postdata()` does **not** assign the global `$post` variable so it's important that you do this yourself.*" - see the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata). I mean, auto-generating excerpts relies upon the global `$post` object, so you need to assign it to a valid `WP_Post` instance.

Comment: OK so apparently there is a bug in get_the_excerpt().  See my notes in the question above.

Comment: Try doing it this way: `global $post; $rp = wp_get_recent_posts( [...], OBJECT );` and use `foreach ($rp as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); ... }` - and change those `$p['ID']` to `$post->ID`.

Comment: "*I can pass any post ID, and it always returns an excerpt for the current post.*" - if the post (with that ID) don't have manual excerpt, then you'd always get an auto-generated excerpt from the current post - i.e. the one referenced by the global `$post` object. It's a limitation in `wp_trim_excerpt()` which is hooked to `get_the_excerpt` (a filter that's applied via `get_the_excerpt()`) and which generates the *automatic* post excerpt.

Comment: So if the docs had explained it as well as you did, I could have avoided 2 hours of unnecessary searching. Thanks.